# IPA file unable to run on colleague's phone or untethered from workstation using Meteorjs+ReactJS+Mongodb

Tags: xcode, mongodb, reactjs, meteor, ipa

I am new to IOS development and have come across an issue and need some help.

I am trying to create an iOS application to target to work on iPhones. I am using MeteorJS, ReactJS with MongoDB for a database. 
When I run the ‘meteor run ios’ command I am able to get the Xcode project. 
I am also able to load the Xcode project within Xcode and generate the IPA file to demo on my iPhone using ITunes from my MacBook Pro. 
When I try to run the application from my iPhone everything works - meaning I was able to connect to the local database (localhost:3001 mongodb). Also, the tests on the application only work when my phone is connected to the Mac.

Now, when I try to export the application and want a colleague to test the iPA file does not work. The IPA file gets installed on the colleague’s phone, however application does not work.

I think I’ve followed the process as required for Adhoc Provisioning profiles however I am not sure whether Im doing this right - because possibly the database is not being packaged with the IPA file?

Could someone please help / Guide?

Answer (score 0):

When running a build produced by `meteor run ios`, the application on the phone tries to connect to a server running locally on your machine over the networked formed on the physical Lightning cable connection.

While you can configure the iOS client to connect to your machine over your local network, this solution introduces other problems you won't expect. Deploy your application to Galaxy, configure your iOS settings to use the URL on Galaxy, and make a production deployment of your iOS application. Then the iOS application will try to connect to an accessible public Internet URL (your Galaxy deployment), rather than your inaccessible local machine.

See the documentation for details.

Comment: Thank you so much DoctorPangloss.

Answer (score 0):

```
meteor run ios-device --mobile-server=http://ip:port
```

worked for me